# Black view is comming while hiding a keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextview

Here is the some piece of code I written for moving textview when user start typing in textview.

Here is the code,

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    if(textView == _textViewMsg || textView == _subjectView ){
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
   // return YES;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    if(textView == _textViewMsg || textView == _subjectView ){
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    }
    return YES;
}


- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-50,320,460)];
}

-(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,60,320,520)];
}
```

[image]

When I click on textview (in Subject) view in moving and I am able to type in textview. It is working fine. (Image 1)

When I click on done button, while hiding i.e at the time of keyboard hide one black view is coming (check Image 2) for few seconds, and then again normal view come.

Edit:

**Solution** : @michael gives me solution just now

changing `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` to `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` it works for me.

**New Problem Occurred** : 
When I start typing in first 2 textviews i.e Requester, firstname & lastname...I am not able to type in it, because it is moving up.

Comment: Can you confirm the same issue happens on a real device rather than just the simulator?

Comment: same thing is happening is real device also.

Comment: Instead of adding observer in the textfield delegate, add them to viewDidLoad and remove them in dealloc or viewDidDisappear or something.
Instead of changing the frame of self.view, handle it gracefully by adding all these on a separate view, making it subview of self.view and then moving that separate view. OR use IQKeyBoardManager, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: @Ajinkya I used already IQKeyBoardManager library still I am getting this issue.

Comment: In that view there are 9 view from that 5 are textview and 4 are textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened because you changing frame of your view after keyboard did disappear, when system animation is completed. Quick fix: change  `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` to `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`

But I want to point few other items in you code, if you don't mind.

**1:**
You are subscribing for notifications each time user begin editing. It means that when user start typing second time, you code will be triggered twice. It is much more more appropriate to subscribe for notifications on `viewDidAppear` and unsubscribe on `viewWillDisappear`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

**2:**
Then you changing your frame to constant value. But now apple support different keyboards with different size not to mention that keyboards size vary on different devices and in different possible modes. So it is much more wise to get the size of keyboard from notification:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [[aNotification.userInfo valueForKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect overlap =  CGRectIntersection( self.view.frame, keyboardFrame);
    // Setup new frmae according to overlap, for example reduce size by half of overlap, and move up by another half
    CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y -= overlap.size.height / 2.0
    newFrame.size.height -= overlap.size.height / 2.0
    self.view.frame = newFrame;
}
```

**3:**
Animations: You can fetch keyboard animation duration from notification as well: 
`UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey`:

```
NSTimeInterval duration = [[aNotification.userInfo  valueForKey: UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    self.view.frame = newFrame;
}];
```

**4**
As it seems your working with scroll view (UITableView and UICollectioView are scroll view), you can instead of changing frame, change content inset (add empty space to bottom scroll view)

`[self.view setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, overlap.size.height, 0)];`

**5**
Consider using AutoLayout.

Comment: my problem is solved but when I start typing in first 2 textviews i.e Requester textview and firstname textview ....I am not able to type in it, because it is moving up. Rest of working fine

Comment: Answer updated, and in your original code you are moving view up, so perhaps you should do this, or at least check what field you are editing and make sure it will kept on screen. You can play with edge insets and scroll offsets to  scroll field you are editing to proper position.

Answer (score 1):

adding observers should be there in viewdidload. try moving the code of adding observers for keyboard to viewdidload.

**Edit**

Instead of did... notification type check with will...
so replace UIKeyboardDidShowNotification with UIKeyboardWillShow and UIKeyboardDidHideNotification with UIKeyboardWillHide.

Comment: not working. I tried adding observers in viewdidload method.

Answer (score 0):

Use of IQKeyboardManager framework will help to handle keyboard hide and unhide issues,

Most efficient way for keyboard handling: [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

**Method 1:**
You can use a Cocoa Pod file for IQKeyboardManager Library.

1. init the pod file.
2. pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
3. install Pod file.

**Method 2:**

Download IQKeyboardManger SDK from github and drag & drop inside your project file.

Swift code snippet:

import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

  IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true

  return true
}
```

}

Objective-C Snippet:

```
#import <IQKeyboardManager/IQKeyboardManager.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //ONE LINE OF CODE.
    //Enabling keyboard manager(Use this line to enable managing distance between keyboard & textField/textView).
    [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:YES];
return true;
}
```

Hope this will help you to resolve your keyboard hide and unhide UI issues.

Comment: very useful answer.

Comment: my problem is solved but when I start typing in first 2 textviews i.e Requester textview and firstname textview ....I am not able to type in it, because it is moving up. Rest of working fine

Comment: View will go up only if you select bottom textview's. It will work fine, if you are starting from FirstName initially. Also you can use Left and right arrow to move to current textfield or textview.